# UniversalImageLoader "ImageView is reused" in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

I have a problem using UIL with ViewPager. I call displayImage(...) in instantiateItem method of pagerAdapter (just like in the sample project in [UIL github repo](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample)).

But, since ViewPager is reusing ImageViews, it defines the same ImageView for previous, current and next pages. So when I create the PagerAdapter, first instantiateItem() is called 3 times and then displayImage() is called 3 times. But since the ImageView is reused and associated with third page, I get "ImageView is reused for another image. Task is cancelled." and only the third page's image is loaded.  The first two are cancelled.

However, the UIL sample project doesn't face this problem. I looked through the whole sample project and couldn't see any difference with mine. So I'm really confused.

Here's my code snippet:

```
private class PhotoPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    PhotoPagerAdapter() {
        inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
        ImageViewTouch imageView = (ImageViewTouch) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);

        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        ((ActivityViewPager) getActivity()).imageLoader.displayImage(imageURLs.get(position), imageView, options, null);

        ...

    }
}
```